# Can questions about fanfics or comics based on official released Anime or Manga be made in anime SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, acceptable-questions

I made a similar question about this before, but since I didnt get an answer, I'll try to explain differently this one.

Can questions about fanfics or comics based on official released Anime or Manga be made in anime SE?

I believe some of them are already being made (such as questions about the One Punch Comic free webseries, the original, not the paid manga)

I'm interested on this, because some animes are borrowing ideas from fanfics/ fan made comics , and then you want to ask something else about them (right now I cant remember the name of a DB fanfic/comic and I would like to ask its name)

Besides, how can you tell a fanfic/comic is not "manga". If manga simply means japanese comic, wasnt the One Punch Man webseries "manga" before it was released as a paid manga? And if manga simply means "comic" for japanese, wouldnt a fanfiction/comic based in anime would be manga for them? and therefore for us since we borrowed from them the word?

Comment: I _think_ we've generally been permissive about stuff that hasn't been "officially" published yet (like webtoons and webnovels). These are, however, distinct from fanfics/etc in that they are not _derivative_ works. We have a pretty clear bright-line way of distinguishing fanworks from non-fanworks. I have a strong gutfeel that we should _not_ have questions about fanworks. Note that the "original" OPM comic is not excluded under this rule, because it is not a derivative of any other existing work.

Comment: (Side note: I don't think it is useful for us to think deeply about the definitions of the words "anime" and "manga" when determining what questions we should and shouldn't allow. "Originalism" in the sense of "what would a Japanese speaker mean when they say _anime_?" is particularly un-useful given that "anime" and "manga" are reasonably well-assimilated English words with their own senses nowadays.)

Comment: yeah, you better dont because I just asked a japanese and any fanfic for them is manga.